# Django startproject UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, django

Im using ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have installed django (latest version, 1.10). But when i tried to run command `django-admin startproject beta` i got issue

```
bisguzar@komodor64:~/Masaüstü/projeler/csgobetting$ django-admin.py startproject beta
```

Here is my error Traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    management.execute_from_command_line()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.10.dev20160327014941-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 362, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.10.dev20160327014941-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.10.dev20160327014941-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 297, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.10.dev20160327014941-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.10.dev20160327014941-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/commands/startproject.py", line 33, in handle
    super(Command, self).handle('project', project_name, target, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.10.dev20160327014941-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/templates.py", line 162, in handle
    if new_path.endswith(extensions) or filename in extra_files:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 19: ordinal not in range(128)
bisguzar@komodor64:~/Masaüstü/projeler/csgobetting$ echo $LANG
tr_TR.UTF-8
bisguzar@komodor64:~/Masaüstü/projeler/csgobetting$
```

'

When I test starproject with django 1.6 its succesful. Thanks a lot...

Comment: Note that your traceback shows you installed the 1.10 development version. You shouldn't, you should use the released 1.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Turkish characters (`Masaüstü`) in your pathname are the problem. Try creating your project under another (preferably shorter) directory, such as `/var/www/projeler`.

Comment: But they should work, Python is quite capable of using non-ascii paths.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I don't know, but django-admin causes problems since 1.7 or 1.8beta (I can't exactly remember) with Turkish characters in pathnames.